# PHP/MYSQL Code doesn't echo success

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey guy's this code isn't echoing the success it inserts the info but just doesn't echo the success mind helping?

If you guy's can post a answer with the code fix would be great thank you all for your help :)

Error Code:

```
<?php

include 'config.inc.php';

$con = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DATA);

if(isset($_POST["strUsername"])) {
    /** PREVENTS DATA MANIPULATION **/
    $sign['NAME'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strUsername"]));
    $sign['PASS'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strPassword"]));
    $sign['PASS'] = gen_token($sign['PASS'], $sign['NAME']);
    $sign['AGE'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["intAge"]));
    $sign['DOB'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strDOB"]));
    $sign['EMAIL'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strEmail"]));
    $sign['GENDER'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strGender"]));
    $sign['EYE'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["intColorEye"]));
    $sign['CLASSID'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["ClassID"]));
    $sign['SKIN'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["intColorSkin"]));
    $sign['HAIR'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["intColorHair"]));
    $sign['ID'] = $con->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['HairID']));

    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '{$sign['NAME']}'");

    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {

        die("status=Taken&strReason=The username is already in use by another character.");
    }

    $sql2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '{$sign['EMAIL']}'");

    if ($sql2->num_rows > 0) {

        die("status=Taken&strReason=The email is already in use by another character.");

    } else {

        /** SETS HAIRNAME & HAIRFILE **/
        switch ($sign['ID']) {
            /** MALE HAIR **/
            case 52:
                $hairname = 'Default';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Default.swf';
                break;
            case 55:
                $hairname = 'Goku1';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Goku1.swf';
                break;
            case 58:
                $hairname = 'Goku2';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Goku2.swf';
                break;
            case 92:
                $hairname = 'Ponytail8';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Ponytail8.swf';
                break;
            case 64:
                $hairname = 'Normal2';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Normal2.swf';
                break;
            case 349:
                $hairname = 'SuggestedHair';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/SuggestedHair.swf';
                break;
            case 284:
                $hairname = 'SandBoy';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/SandBoy.swf';
                break;
            case 383:
                $hairname = 'AQDemonHunter1';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/AQDemonHunter1.swf';
                break;
            case 396:
                $hairname = 'MQElegant';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/MQElegant.swf';
                break;
            case 390:
                $hairname = 'DFWarStyle';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/DFWarStyle.swf';
                break;
            case 275:
                $hairname = 'FauxHawk2';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/FauxHawk2.swf';
                break;
            case 398:
                $hairname = 'MQSwift';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/MQSwift.swf';
                break;
             case 324:
                $hairname = 'Troll3Human';
                $hairfile = 'hair/M/Troll3Human.swf';
                break;

            /** FEMALE HAIR **/
            case 14:
                $hairname = 'Pig1Bangs1';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Pig1Bangs1.swf';
                break;
            case 18:
                $hairname = 'Pig2Bangs2';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Pig2Bangs2.swf';
                break;
            case 26:
                $hairname = 'Pony2Bangs2';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Pony2Bangs2.swf';
                break;
            case 83:
                $hairname = 'Bangs2Long';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Bangs2Long.swf';
                break;
            case 84:
                $hairname = 'Bangs3Long';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Bangs3Long.swf';
                break;
            case 285:
                $hairname = 'SandHairGirl';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/SandHairGirl.swf';
                break;
            case 379:
                $hairname = 'Bangs3Long';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Bangs3Long.swf';
                break;
            case 375:
                $hairname = 'AQCasual';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/AQCasual.swf';
                break;
            case 380:
                $hairname = 'MQRibbon';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/MQRibbon.swf';
                break;
            case 277:
                $hairname = 'Dragonhawk';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/Dragonhawk.swf';
                break;
            case 328:
                $hairname = 'TrollFem1Human';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/TrollFem1Human.swf';
                break;
            case 330:
                $hairname = 'TrollFem3Human';
                $hairfile = 'hair/F/TrollFem3Human.swf';
                break;
        }

        $con->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Username`, `Password`, `Access`, `ActivationFlag`, `Age`, `Gender`, `Email`, `Level`, `Gold`, `Coins`, `Exp`, `ColorHair`, `ColorSkin`, `ColorEye`, `ColorBase`, `ColorTrim`, `ColorAccessory`, `DateCreated`, `UpgradeExpire`, `UpgradeDays`, `BankSlots`, `HouseSlots`, `BagSlots`, `HairID`, `HairFile`, `HairName`, `Permamute`, `Quests`, `Settings`, `Achievement`, `LastArea`, `Country`) VALUES ('{$sign['NAME']}', '{$sign['PASS']}', '1', '5', '{$sign['AGE']}', '{$sign['GENDER']}', '{$sign['EMAIL']}', '1', '10000', '500', '0', '{$sign['hycc']}', '{$sign['SKIN']}', '{$sign['EYE']}', '0', '0', '0', '2011-05-23 21:02:33', '2011-05-23 21:02:33', '0', '20', '20', '40', '{$sign['ID']}', '${hairfile}', '{$hairname}', '0', '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0', '0', '', 'US')");

        /** SELECTS NEW USER ID **/
        $sql3 = $con->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE Username='{$sign['NAME']}'");
        $user = $sql3->fetch_assoc();
        $user_id = $user['id'];

    switch ($sign['CLASSID']) {
        case 2: // Warrior
                $con->query("INSERT INTO users_items (itemid, userid, equipped, equipment, level, quantity, inbank, enhid) VALUES ('2', '$user_id', '1', 'ar', '1', '1', '0', '1')");
                break;
        case 4: // Rogue
                $con->query("INSERT INTO users_items (itemid, userid, equipped, equipment, level, quantity, inbank, enhid) VALUES ('3', '$user_id', '1', 'ar', '1', '1', '0', '1')");
                break;
        case 3: // Mage
                $con->query("INSERT INTO users_items (itemid, userid, equipped, equipment, level, quantity, inbank, enhid) VALUES ('4', '$user_id', '1', 'ar', '1', '1', '0', '1')");
                break;
        case 5: // Ranger
                $con->query("INSERT INTO users_items (itemid, userid, equipped, equipment, level, quantity, inbank, enhid) VALUES ('5', '$user_id', '1', 'ar', '1', '1', '0', '1')");
                break;
        }


        $con->query("INSERT INTO users_items (itemid, userid, equipped, equipment, level, quantity, inbank, enhid) VALUES ('1', '$user_id', '1', 'Weapon', '1', '1', '0', '1')");

        /** SUCCESS **/ 
        echo "status=Success";
    }
} else {
    die("status=Error&strReason=Invalid Input.");
}

function gen_token($pass, $salt) {
    $salt = strtolower($salt);
    $str = hash("sha512", $pass.$salt);
    $len = strlen($salt);
    return strtoupper(substr($str, $len, 17));
}
?>
```

Comment: To being with, your code assumes that SQL queries can't have errors and will never fail. That's often not true, esp. in the development phase. Don't omit error checking, no matter how solid your code looks to you. Additionally: 1) If you use `stripslashes()` because your server has magic quotes enabled you should disable magic quotes instead. 2) What's wrong with prepared statements that so many people prefer to escape input fields one by one?

Comment: oops posted at wrong question ...sorry

Comment: try using `exit;` after echo statement to check if it really reaches there.

Answer (score 0):

So the INSERT is corrrectly made but a bug blocks the script to go until the line :

```
echo "status=Success";
```

Try to insert this at the beginning of your script and post the answer :

```
$debug = true;
ini_set('display_startup_errors', $debug);
ini_set('display_errors', $debug);
ini_set('html_errors', $debug);
```

By the way, which insert is done? Into users, into users_items first time, and do you go until the second insert into users_items?